# facebook small issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

If anyone is familiar with the fql query, why am I getting this error for the next query:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20post_id,%20actor_id,%20target_id,%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20=%20302056140380%20AND%20updated_time%20%3E%201111111

This is the page:https://www.facebook.com/Inna?sk=wall
All I want to do is to retrive the last posts from Inna's wall.

Thank you very much;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a valid **access_token** with the FQL request even though the data is public. You can test it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/). You won't need to have any permissions granted to access the feed, but you will need to provide the token.

You will need an `access_token` of type "Any Valid" as defined [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/). In short, it means that you can use any `access_token` that hasn't expired. One easy to obtain `access_token` is an **app access token** which you can obtain by going to:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_tokenclient_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

You will find **YOUR_APP_ID** and **YOUR_APP_SECRET** under your [created apps page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) (or you can create one there if you don't have one).

When you provide the app id and secret to the oauth, you will receive an `access_token` which you can use for the request until the token expires.

Comment: I've read something about that. Application ID, etc. . . But I don't have any ideea how could I do that? How can I obtain the access token? I've seen something about some requests that are made but for each user that visits my site. Well, I don't need that. I need to access that wall once at 10 seconds let's say, and grab the posts, and ater that, each post comments. The weird thing is that I am able to grab a post comments via fql, but I can't get the posts . . . So, how can I provide a valid access token? It will be the same for each request?

Comment: you are right. It works there. But where can I get that access token?

Comment: @Iosub I've updated my answer on information how to obtain one.